# Python script to get contents of personal-preferences field in Plone

Tags: plone, template-tal, zpt

I have a custom registration and @@personal-preferences page in my Plone 4 site, it has a few extra fields such as an area for people to paste their social networking links and what their company position is - it also displays the date they were registered on the site. ( I used [collective.examples.userdata](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/collective.examples.userdata) to accomplish this)

I am successfully able to reference these fields in  page template using the definitions below:

```
tal:define="membership context/portal_membership;
            info python:membership.getMemberInfo(user.getId());
            userPosition python:user.getProperty('position');
            userFB python:user.getProperty('facebook');
            userLinkedIn python:user.getProperty('linkedin');
            userTwitter python:user.getProperty('twitter');
            userRegDay python:user.getProperty('regday')"
```

I am trying to write a Python script which will grab the last definiton of `python:user.getProperty('regday')` and do some math to display how long they have been registered on the site.

My script is calling memberLength and is in my custom folder, I have been calling it with the following:

```
tal:content="context/memberLength"
```

I have tried many things but constantly get traceback errors, so I'm not really sure how to accomplish telling Python to get those field details.. I've tried the following (the examples below are me **merely trying to get python to get the field information**):

Python script:

```
membership = context.portal_membership.getMemberInfo()
return "%s" % membership
```

However that returns a dictionary of the basic current users information (username, description etc), there is nothing useful for me there - none of my custom fields ever appear in this dict.

```
membership = context.getProperty('regday', 'Could not find')
return "%s" % membership
```

The above returns my 'Could not find' message, so that doesn't work either, the same goes for the script below:

```
membership = context.portal_membership.getProperty('regday','Could not find')
return "%s" % membership
```

I tried this:

```
membership = context.portal_membership.user.getProperty('regday','Could not find')
return "%s" % membership
```

However I got an `AttributeError: user` traceback message.

I also tried this tal statement: `context/userRegDay/membershipLegth` but that gave me an error, so I tried the Python alternative `context.userRegDay.membershipLegth()` - but they didn't work.

All of my fields above exist in the `Properties` tab of my `portal_memberdata` page in the ZMI.

Google isn't helping me so much here, all I can find is [this page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8734872/plone-4-changing-the-login-name-on-the-personal-information-form) however it doesn't really cover what I'm trying to do as far as I can tell.

Can anyone tell me how I can get my UserRegDay variable passed to my Python script? Or am I going about this all wrong?

Apologies in advance to any experienced Plone people who's blood pressure may rise as a result of reading my attempts at this.

Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

`getMemberInfo` returns only the default user data.
it's hardcoded in membership.py of Products.PlonePAS

```python
    memberinfo = {'fullname'    : member.getProperty('fullname'),
                  'description' : member.getProperty('description'),
                  'location'    : member.getProperty('location'),
                  'language'    : member.getProperty('language'),
                  'home_page'   : member.getProperty('home_page'),
                  'username'    : member.getUserName(),
                  'has_email'   : bool(member.getProperty('email')),
                 }
```

Try this in a python script:

```python
userid = 'userid'  # fill in a user id
member = context.portal_membership.getMemberById(userid)

print member.getProperty('regday')
return printed
```

Please tell if this is not working, then we can investigate  further. 
I already extended the user data successfully, but not with collective.examples.userdata, but manually.

regards

Comment: Unfortunately I'm having some problems, I think maybe the userdata.examples is causing some sort of issue with it, more likely my Python knowledge is letting me down... `member.getProperty('regday')` seems to be returning an object instead of a string, if I specify an alternative field such as 'username' it also returns an object. FYI my modified script is: http://pastie.org/8610556 however if I do a straight copy & paste on your code & update the userid it also returns the object, I tried building it all into a list but that gave me a traceback (`for item in member: append.mylist(item)`)

Comment: UPDATE: I tried `member.getProperty('regday','couldnt find')` and it returned 'couldnt find' so I'm thinking something else has gone wrong. Perhaps a better way of doing this is to avoid `collective.examples.userdata`?

Comment: @Dan `collective.examples.userdata` defines some additional fields, like `gender`. Do they work on your site? Another question, did you actually  customize the `collective.examples.userdata` or do you have your own implementation? or both installed at the same time? Can you also paste the output of the script (which object?).

Comment: No the extra fields don't work on my installation, I am limited to booleans, and strings only (even the Date field breaks the installation). Well if I take your script as is, I get the following: `<object object at 0x4668450>` that's calling it using the TALES: `<p tal:content="context/myScript" />`

Comment: I guess this this should be the first step, you need to get the `collective.examples.userdata` to work on your site. Then you can customize it. But, can you print a plone default user property? like 'fullname'? just click on the test-tab of the python script, you don't have to call it from a zpt.

Comment: using the script: http://pastie.org/8617921 (trying to get the username property) I receive this output when clicking 'test' from my custom folder within the ZMI: `<object object at 0x42f7480>`

Comment: `username` is not a memberdata property. check http://pastie.org/8619784, getting the fullname works on a vanilla plone site, this should work on your site too.